# CouchDB View Pattern Matching Combining Numeric and Alpha in Key

Tags: view, couchdb

Thus far all the views I've created in couchdb have used numeric values in the keys. I've had a bit of a surprise when adding alpha characters to the keys.

My view is returning values as expected:

```
[2011,12,5,14,22,"foo"]
[2011,12,5,14,23,"foo"]
[2011,12,5,14,42,"bar"]
[2011,12,5,15,2,"foo"]
[2011,12,5,15,21,"foo"]
[2011,12,5,15,23,"foo"]
[2011,12,5,16,2,"foo"]
[2011,12,5,16,21,"foo"]
[2011,12,5,16,23,"foo"]
[2011,12,5,16,42,"bar"]
```

However, when I query these using a start key of:

```
    [2011,12,5,14,16,"foo"]
```

and an end key of

```
[2011,12,5,16,60,"foo\ufff0"]


http://couchdb_host:5984/the_db/_design/cf/_view/errors?startkey=[2011,12,5,14,16,%22foo%22]&endkey=[2011,12,5,16,60,%22foo\ufff0%22]&group_level=6
```

I keep getting values for "bar" in the results:

```
    {"rows":[
{"key":[2011,12,5,14,22,"foo"],"value":2},
{"key":[2011,12,5,14,23,"foo"],"value":1},
{"key":[2011,12,5,14,42,"bar"],"value":1},
{"key":[2011,12,5,15,2,"foo"],"value":1},
{"key":[2011,12,5,15,21,"foo"],"value":2},
{"key":[2011,12,5,15,23,"foo"],"value":1},
{"key":[2011,12,5,16,2,"foo"],"value":1},
{"key":[2011,12,5,16,21,"foo"],"value":2},
{"key":[2011,12,5,16,23,"foo"],"value":1},
{"key":[2011,12,5,16,42,"bar"],"value":1}
]}
```

Where am I falling down? I expected "bar" to be ignored, and anything beginning with "foo" to be returned. It all seems so simple on paper!

Clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CouchDB is returning all keys that sort higher (or equal) to startkey and less than (or equal to) endkey. [2011,12,5,14,42,"bar"] sorts higher than [2011,12,5,14,16,"foo"] because 42 is higher than 16 and sorts lower than [2011,12,5,16,60,"foo\ufff0"] because 42 is lower than 60.

This page describes how keys are sorted: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation

Comment: As Robert said, your the range of your query is a lot wider than you are expecting. If you only want to search for foo in a range you will have to put it first like ['foo', 2011,12,5,14,16] and query like startkey=[%22foo%22, 2011,12,5,14,16]  endkey=[%22foo%22,2011,12,5,16,60].